# opt 101P photodiode for light communication

Tags: output, photodiode, light-sensor

The following is the circuit for *Light communication using opt 101P photodiode*.

[image]

*Connections are* COM pin (pin 8), and pin 3(-V) are grounded. Input volatge(pin 1) Vcc = 9 V . OPT 101 has a photodiode and a transimpedance amplifier.

Here is the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt101.pdf) for opt 101P.

I have given proper connections according to the datasheet. **But the problem here is opt 101P photodiode is not detecting the light**.

If the photodiode is illuminated with light, small photocurrent produced is converted into the voltage by transimpedance amplifier at pin 5. **But in my test, I didn't get any voltage at the output pin 5.** Can anyone specify how to test opt101P photodiode?

Comment: How about a link to the data sheet?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt101.pdf

Comment: @Veena [edit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/272130/edit) your question to include that link!

Comment: And show us what you have done. "I did everything correctly" isn't helpful. Either you didn't then you need someone to point it out, or you did, and then you have your test circuit and the diode is faulty.

Comment: Please state what supply you have used.

Comment: @Marcus.... http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt101.pdf

Comment: Also, this looks like a very fundamental question – you have the data sheet, thus you should be able to know what you *should* be seeing on the device's output. The fact that you're asking how to test the thing points to you not being versed with basic electronics – so if we had to write an answer for you, we'd need to start with Adam and Eve. It's thus absolutely **necessary to include what you've done, including your schematic**, and then explain what "is not detecting" means to you.

Comment: @Veena I did not need the same link again, you must [**edit**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/272130/edit) your question to include the link, and the info Andy, PlasmaHH and I have requested from you. **Do not add info that is central to the question as comments**.

Comment: And, to add to the above, the big suspicion from the guys here (and hopefully I'm speaking for them) is that you HAVE NOT wired it up as per the data sheet THEREFORE you must show what you have done and not point at a data sheet (again). It's just plain bloody rude to do that.

Comment: It's been half an hour. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @Veena See [How to ask a question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then Edit your post with _data sheet_ , _add schematic_  and describe your problem.

Comment: The output pin of the photodiode not showing any voltage variation...

Comment: @Veena **EDIT** your question to include that information. Also: "not showing any voltage variation" when you do *what*? How do you measure "voltage variation"? We're not sitting inside your head. You need to give us **all** information, and **in the question**, not as comments.

Comment: @Veena seriously, though, it took you **9** comments from our side and you still haven't included the link in your question. If you can't follow simple advice, please don't expect people to help you for free.

Comment: Also, have you actually tried to read the pin numbers on the blurry screenshot of your schematic?

Comment: @ Marcus...COM pin (pin 8),and pin 3(-V) are grounded.Input volatge Vcc=9V is given at pin 1.OPT 101 has a photodiode and a transimpedance amplifier.If the photodiode is illuminated with light,small photocurrent produced is converted into voltage by transimpedance amplifier at pin 5.But in my test, I am not get any voltage at the output pin 5.

Comment: You say this 101P thing is a photodiode, but is shown as a resistor in your schematic.  I also can't make out what the left chip is.  Too much confusion, inconsistent, and missing information.  Closing this mess.

Comment: @Veena **How hard can it actually be to include information in the question rather than the comments, after being told so more than five times?**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to feed an AC coupled signal into an OPAMP circuit (LM324) that is powered from a single rail. At best, you might recover a half rectified signal because the common-mode input range for an LM324 is not specified to be lower than 0V.

At worse, you might see no signal at all because of the input offset voltage of the LM324. I also see NO power supply decoupling on the LM324 or photodiode chip and I'm pretty sure these will be recommended.

> If the photodiode is illuminated with light,small photocurrent
>   produced is converted into voltage by transimpedance amplifier at pin
>   5.But in my test, I am not get any voltage at the output pin

This will produce a DC voltage at the output of the OPT101 and, apart from a small transient as you switch on the illuminations, capacitor C1 (4.7 nF) will block that DC voltage from sending any further signal to the badly-connected (or badly powered) op-amp. What can you expect with an AC coupled amplifier?

Comment: I'm usually really not of the vengeful kind, but in this case, I think it'd be both more helpful for the overal EE.SE quality as well as for OP to leave them sit with their problem until they brought their question into a clear shape. By the way, fully agreeing; the CR highpass between OPT thing and the external opamp has a >1kHz cut-off, so OP wouldn't even see what's happening in a properly biased setup.